# set the time in Alarm manager Android - alarm fired instantly

Tags: android, calendar, alarmmanager

Here i am trying to set the alarm by using AlarmManger class. It is working fine with me but when i set the alarm time after Hours or mins from time picker,It will start the instantly when i save that alarm. the alarm. I need to alarm go off until i set the time. 
Below is my code is working but starts the alarm immediately when i save.

I am setting time only with the time picker.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR,Calendar.MONTH,Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,mHour,mMinute);
PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AddAlarm.this, REQUEST_CODE, intent, 0);
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), sender);
```

If i take below code alarm is not working..

```
 Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, mHour);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, mMinute);
PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AddAlarm.this, REQUEST_CODE, intent, 0);
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), sender);
```

Help me should i change in the to work properly.Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 4):

The second code should normally work for dated alarms.

Keep in mind:
If you set the HOUR and MINUTE you set them for the current day eg HOUR = 1 and MINUTE = 30 means you set an alarm for 01:30 AM.
If it is over, you might get the alarm right now.

When you like to create an alarm in the future with 1:30 to go, then use the **calendar.add(..,..)** method.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do with this line:

```
calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR,Calendar.MONTH,Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,mHour,mMinute);
```

but I'm pretty certain it doesn't do what you want.  This will set the calendar to be the hour & minute you have chosen on the 5th of March of the year 1 AD.  When you convert this to milliseconds, you'll get 0 out, because that's before the earliest date that can be represented in milliseconds.

You also have a different Calendar API related problem in this line:

```
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, mHour);
```

Here, your problem is that the Calendar.HOUR field refers to the hour in 12-hour notation, whereas your mHour is presumably using 24-hour notation (otherwise you'd also need an AM/PM field to hold a full day's worth of times).  You want Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY instead.